# combining 2 arrays to make objects of the combination with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function fillBoxes() {
  var s = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
  var v = ['box1', 'box2', 'box3'];
  var lengtha = s.length;
  var lengthb = v.length;
  
  if (lengtha > lengthb) {
    console.log("not enough objects to contain data.");
  } else {
    var resp = [];
    var respb = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      resp.push(s[i]);
    }
    
    for (var j = 0; j < v.length; j++) {
      respb.push(document.getElementById(v[j]).innerHTML = resp);
    }
    
    console.log(respb);
  }
}
```

```css
.testToggle {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}

.pressme {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: gray;
}

.gen {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: thin #000000 solid;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="fillBoxes();" id="pressme" class="pressme" title="yoooo">Click Me</div>
<div id="drop" class="testToggle">sdfgsdfg</div>
<div class="gen" id="box1"></div>
<div class="gen" id="box2"></div>
<div class="gen" id="box3"></div>
```

The result I get each container has the array in it.  How can I split the array up so that box1 has only data1, box2 has only data2, and box3 has only data3 instead of box1 having data1,data2, and data3.

and please no jquery.

Comment: Is that what those data sets look like? Is data1 actually a string or is it a placeholder for an array or object? Are the values initially set or do they change dynamically? Will the array positions of boxes and data always be the same?

Comment: FYI: There is a *"Tidy"* button in snippets (on the top-left) which will automatically format the code: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: they are actually passed through an ajax call in a library im creating and they will be dynamic string that composed of html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already have the array, just add the index :

```
.innerHTML = resp[j]
                 ^^^
```

```js
function fillBoxes() {
  var s = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
  var v = ['box1', 'box2', 'box3'];
  var lengtha = s.length;
  var lengthb = v.length;
  if (lengtha > lengthb) {
    console.log("not enough objects to contain data.");
  } else {
    var resp = [];
    var respb = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      resp.push(s[i]);
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < v.length; j++) {
      respb.push(document.getElementById(v[j]).innerHTML = resp[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.testToggle {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}

.pressme {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: gray;
}

.gen {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: thin #000000 solid;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="fillBoxes();" id="pressme" class="pressme" title="yoooo">Click Me</div>
<div id="drop" class="testToggle">sdfgsdfg</div>
<div class="gen" id="box1"></div>
<div class="gen" id="box2"></div>
<div class="gen" id="box3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks thats what i was looking for i knew i was close.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use index while assigning with document.getById for below line

```
respb.push(document.getElementById(v[j]).innerHTML = resp[j]);
```

working code for refernce:

```js
function fillBoxes() {
  var s = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
  var v = ['box1', 'box2', 'box3'];
  var lengtha = s.length;
  var lengthb = v.length;
  
  if (lengtha > lengthb) {
    console.log("not enough objects to contain data.");
  } else {
    var resp = [];
    var respb = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      resp.push(s[i]);
    }
    
    for (var j = 0; j < v.length; j++) {
      respb.push(document.getElementById(v[j]).innerHTML = resp[j]);
    }
    
    console.log(respb);
  }
}
```

```css
.testToggle {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}

.pressme {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: gray;
}

.gen {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: thin #000000 solid;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="fillBoxes();" id="pressme" class="pressme" title="yoooo">Click Me</div>
<div id="drop" class="testToggle">sdfgsdfg</div>
<div class="gen" id="box1"></div>
<div class="gen" id="box2"></div>
<div class="gen" id="box3"></div>
```

codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zYOPYzx

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're looking to do, except maybe add text to the dom. Try not to set innerHTML. This can be a source of vulnerability in some instances.

```js
function fillBoxes(){
  const ids = ['box1','box2','box3'];
  const data = ['data1','data2','data3'];
  if (ids.length !== data.length) {
    console.log("not enough objects to contain data.");
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
      let el = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
      let content = document.createTextNode(data[i]);
      el.appendChild(content);
    }
  }
}
```